# Can we Arrange subsets of {1,...,8}, each on of size 2, in cycle such that any two subsets appear next to each other iff they disjoint?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I saw this question in an old graph theory exam:

> Let $A = \left \{  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\right \}$. Can we arrange on a
>   cycle, all $S\in P(A)$ such that $|S|=2$, such that any $2$ subsets
>   can be appear next to each other if and only if they disjoint?

I know I should create a 28-vertices graph, but I don't know how to continue from here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a Hamilton cycle in the [Kneser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph)(8,2) graph.  I found it computationally using a backtracking algorithm in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got this:
Lets define $G=\langle V,E\rangle$ such that $$V=\left \{\left \{ a,b\right\}| a,b \in A \wedge a \neq b\right \}$$ $$\left \{ \left \{ a, b \right \}, \left \{ c, d \right \} \right \} \in E \Leftrightarrow \left \{a, b \right \} \cap \left \{ c, d\right \}=\varnothing$$
Notice that $|V|=28$: this is the number of ways to choose a subset of size $2$, out of a set of size $8$.
Now, for every $v \in V$, there are exactly $15$ neighbours to v:
We want to choose a subset of size $2$, that disjoint from $v$. So we choose subset of size $2$ out of a set of size $6$ (with out v).
$\delta (G) =15$ and $\frac{V(G)}{2} = \frac{28}{2} = 14$, so as Dirac theorem implies - there is an hamiltonian cycle in G.  And we use this cycle as the arrangement.